# Room with PagingSource can't load data from center position of the data list

Tags: android-room, android-paging-3

I'm using jetpack Paging3 with Room. I have a feature that I need to load data start from any page from the database.

for example:
I have a user table. and I defined the user dao like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id")
fun usersPagingSource():PagingSource<Int, User>
```

in view mode I use the dao method like:

```
Pager(config = PagingConfig(
      pageSize = 20,
      prefetchDistance = 5,
      initialLoadSize = 20),
      initialKey = 5,
      pagingSourceFactory = { userDao.usersPagingSource() }
     ).flow.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

The problem is the paging source always return the first page in database first time, but not the 6th page as I want.

If I want to load data from the 6th page data in database first time, what should I do?
Did I miss something about the paging api?